# Process stuck on the entry point

Tags: windows, debuggers, game-hacking, process, entry-point

I'm trying to patch an old game (1998-ish) that runs on windows 95 and windows XP to make it compatible with windows 11.

The current problem with it is that when running the exe file nothing seems to happen, not even an error message that can point in the direction of the problem.
A quick lookup in the task manager showed that the process for the game was running but the window of it is no where to be found.
This lead me to believe that there was a problem in the createWindowExA function but when I opened the game in x32dbg, it didn't even get there because the execution was stuck on the entry point, regardless of how many times I pressed the step into or step over button. The same thing happened in Ollydbg.

Does anyone have any idea what can cause this kind of problem or where to look for to get a clue on how to proceed from here?